# c# delegates refactor learning

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a code snippet as shown below. How can i refactor it to use delegates ? Is it worth refctoring this code to use delegate? Am I wrong in thinking that this is a scenario where delegates could be used? I am trying to learn delegates and want to see the use of them.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {             
        var count = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Logger Type -->");
        var logType = Console.ReadLine();

        if (logType == "A")
        {
            if (count > 10)
            {
                LoggerTypeA.Error(count);
            }
            else
            {
                LoggerTypeA.Warning(count);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (count > 10)
            {
                LoggerTypeB.Error(count);
            }
            else
            {
                LoggerTypeB.Warning(count);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}

internal static class LoggerTypeA
{
    public static void Error(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error {0} from Logger A", count);
    }

    public static void Warning(int counter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Warning {0} from Logger A", counter);
    }
}

internal static class LoggerTypeB
{
    public static void Error(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error {0} from Logger B", count);
    }

    public static void Warning(int counter)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Warning {0} from Logger ", counter);
    }
}
```

Comment: an interface might be better than delegates.

Comment: There is no obvious need for delegates here. Articles about delegates will have examples.

Comment: Can you provide me a simple example where delegate could be used?

Answer (score 1):

Good example of where delegates are useful are [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) and [event handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). For example, you could reimplement LINQ's `Select` and `Where` methods like so:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> MySelect<TSource, TResult>
              (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
        yield return selector(item);
}
public static IEnumerable<T> MyWhere<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                        Func<T, bool> selector)
{
    foreach (T item in source)
        if (selector(item))
            yield return item;
}
```

Then with the lambda syntax you can easily create the methods to do things, like `myList.MyWhere(x => x.Name == "John")`.

It would probably make more sense to use an `interface` in this instance. E.g.

```
public static void Main()
{
    var count = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Logger Type -->");
    var logType = Console.ReadLine();
    ILogger logger = logType == "A" ? (ILogger)new LoggerTypeA() : new LoggerTypeB();
    if (count > 10)
    {
        logger.Error(count);
    }
    else
    {
        logger.Warning(count);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
public interface ILogger
{
    void Error(int count);
    void Warning(int count);
}
internal class LoggerTypeA : ILogger
{
    public void Error(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error {0} from Logger A", count);
    }

    public void Warning(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Warning {0} from Logger A", count);
    }
}

internal class LoggerTypeB : ILogger
{
    public void Error(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error {0} from Logger B", count);
    }

    public void Warning(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Warning {0} from Logger ", count);
    }
}
```

If you still want to be able to use the loggers as `static` methods, you can use [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to let it expose itself as both an `ILogger` and `static` methods:

```
internal class LoggerTypeA : ILogger
{
    public static void Error(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error {0} from Logger A", count);
    }
    void ILogger.Error(int count)
    {
        Error(count);
    }

    public static void Warning(int count)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Warning {0} from Logger A", count);
    }
    void ILogger.Warning(int count)
    {
        Warning(count);
    }
}
```

E.g. with this, the previous code still works, but you can also do `LoggerTypeA.Error(count);`.

A way this could be done with delegates is as follows. As you can see, there's not much improvement over your original method.

```
{
    var count = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("Logger Type -->");
    var logType = Console.ReadLine();
    Action<int> logAction;
    if (logType == "A")
    {
        if (count > 10)
        {
            logAction = LoggerTypeA.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            logAction = LoggerTypeA.Warning;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (count > 10)
        {
            logAction = LoggerTypeB.Error;
        }
        else
        {
            logAction = LoggerTypeB.Warning;
        }
    }
    logAction(count);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a simple delegate example, a scenario where delegate  must be used?

Comment: @user1108205 LINQ and event handlers are two good examples of where delegates are very useful. I've added an example to the top of my answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19405571/failed-to-understand-the-use-of-delegates-in-real-world-scenarios for a similar question.